# Can't upload programs to Raspberry Pi Pico with Arduino

Tags: uploading, raspberrypi-pico

I am trying to use a RP2040 Pico with the Arduino IDE. This is a huge uphill battle. Initially I couldn't get the upload serial port to show up, then copied the "hello world" UF2 to the Pico folder (https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/soft/hello_world.uf2), after which the port showed up in the Arduino ISE 2.0.0 on Windows 10 - but I can't upload any programs. All I get is this error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\light\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\rp2040\hardware\rp2040\1.9.15/tools/uf2conv.py", line 380, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\light\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\rp2040\hardware\rp2040\1.9.15/tools/uf2conv.py", line 360, in main
        drives = get_drives()
      File "C:\Users\light\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\rp2040\hardware\rp2040\1.9.15/tools/uf2conv.py", line 233, in get_drives
        "FileSystem,", "DriveType"])
      File "D:\obj\Windows-Release\37win32_Release\msi_python\zip_win32\subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
      File "D:\obj\Windows-Release\37win32_Release\msi_python\zip_win32\subprocess.py", line 472, in run
      File "D:\obj\Windows-Release\37win32_Release\msi_python\zip_win32\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
      File "D:\obj\Windows-Release\37win32_Release\msi_python\zip_win32\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
    Upload error: Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1
```

This is ultra-weird, because no such folders etc. exist on my drive D:, and I have no idea why it's looking for files on drive D:\ in the first place, because the Arduino IDE is installed on drive C:. And these folders also aren't present on C:.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? I've Googled everything I can find and have so far found nothing helpful. I'm about ready to give up and would REALLY appreciate any help you can give!

Comment: Those paths with the D: drive come from the stacktrace of the library that's used. Whoever built that library did have a D: drive. Nothing to worry about for you.

Comment: The serial port is only used for resetting the chip into the bootloader. Once there it presents as a USB MSD device (hard drive) to which the .uf2 file generated to the IDE gets copied to. It looks like it's not finding that drive. When you upload does the board reset to present a hard drive or not? If not then you can force it by connecting the board while holding in the button on the board. Once it's showing a drive hit upload and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Neither Arduino 1.8.19 nor 2.0.0 can access the RPi Pico via COM. Neither successfully compiles code for it either (maybe it's just me, but if a compilation fails because the IDE can't find a nonexistent file, I do tend to worry about it). Interestingly, the 2.0.0 IDE also can't find the COM port for an ESP32, which appears in the Windows device manager & also in 1.8.19. I'm ditching the RPi Pico in the Arduino ecosystem because I simply don't have more time to waste. Likewise, the Arduino IDE 2.0.0. They are more riddled with bugs than a rotting log in the rainforest.

Answer (score 1):

Installing a generic driver with  https://zadig.akeo.ie/ while the PICO was plugged in solved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

It took me two days to fix that mistake!
Who would have thought that this is due to the missing file "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\framedynos.dll".
When I put the file back in place, everything went back to normal.

UPD:

Turn on "Show verbose output" in Preferences and browse several last lines.
There should be a line like this:

```
C:\Users\light\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\rp2040\tools\pqt-python3\1.0.1-base-3a57aed/python3 -I C:\Users\light\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\rp2040\hardware\rp2040\1.10.0/tools/uf2conv.py --serial COM5 --family RP2040 --deploy C:\Temp\arduino_build_214726/...
```

Copy and run that line in Terminal (Win-R). There may be bug reports to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Arduino:SE.  This doesn't actually provide an answer to the question that was asked.  To ask another question, just click [Ask Question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) above. If you wish, include a link to this question to help provide context.